# Powershell working with Directories

Tags: powershell

Hi new to Powershell only ever butchered existing scripts or worked with bash before.

I am trying to list all directories with one criteria and then execute a commend on their contents.

Basically I want to recursively search all dirs called Processed and remove all items over 31 days. What I have so for are the commands below:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)
$path = "C:\Users\mark.hodgson\Desktop\New folder"
$dirs = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Directory| Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "Processed"} |select-object Fullname
```

When I echo $dirs the list looks good as below:

```
PS C:\Users\mark.hodgson\Desktop\New folder> echo $dirs

FullName                                                          
--------                                                          
C:\Users\mark.hodgson\Desktop\New folder\Folder1\FolderA\Processed
C:\Users\mark.hodgson\Desktop\New folder\Folder1\FolderB\Processed
C:\Users\mark.hodgson\Desktop\New folder\Folder2\Processed        
C:\Users\mark.hodgson\Desktop\New folder\Folder3\Processed        
C:\Users\mark.hodgson\Desktop\New folder\Folder4\Processed        
C:\Users\mark.hodgson\Desktop\New folder\Folder5\Processed
```

but when I try to work with the items as below or even just do an ls it returns or deletes all folders off my desktop!!

```
$dirs | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -eq $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force }
```

same if I use for $dir in $dirs

I must be getting the basics wrong here! I can hard code the paths but would love to do a proper job.

Cheers,

hodgm

Comment: !$_.PSIsContainer -eq $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit  ?  Your condition is wrong here. Replace -eq with -and, I guess.

Comment: The `-eq` in the lat line shoould be an `-and` I'd add `-whatif` while testing to the remove-item

Comment: `!` should be `-not`; or you could replace `-eq` (equals) with `-ne` (does not equal).  http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the current pipeline item inside the `ForEach-Object` body:

```
$dirs | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force }
```

Comment: Perfect that (along with replacing the -eq to -and from the comments above) sorted it!!

Comment: Much appreciated :D

Comment: @hodgm If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left